# C# Visual Studio 2013 Windows Form App Taking Score

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hi having issue adding ( + 10) to my score variable and displaying it, the variable is ScoreNum and is suppose to + 10 when picBigAlien1 is no longer visible (i.e. picBigAlien1.Visible = false) this might be an error due to putting the code in the wrong place. I've been working on this for hours and iv'e used the same method to display scores before on other programs and have never had this issue. It's probably something really simple I just can't spot it. Any help appreciated. Thank you. (C)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Space_Invadors
{
    public partial class frmSpace : Form
    {
        //List of all barrier picture boxes and alien picture boxes
        PictureBox[] barriers;
        PictureBox[] Aliens;
        PictureBox[] Aliens2;
        int ScoreNum = 0;
        bool direction = false;
        public frmSpace()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.barriers = new PictureBox[20];
            this.barriers[0] = picBlock1Part1;
            this.barriers[1] = picBlock1Part2;
            this.barriers[2] = picBlock1Part3;
            this.barriers[3] = picBlock1Part4;
            this.barriers[4] = picBlock2Part1;
            this.barriers[5] = picBlock2Part2;
            this.barriers[6] = picBlock2Part3;
            this.barriers[7] = picBlock2Part4;
            this.barriers[8] = picBlock3Part1;
            this.barriers[9] = picBlock3Part2;
            this.barriers[10] = picBlock3Part3;
            this.barriers[11] = picBlock3Part4;
            this.barriers[12] = picBlock4Part1;
            this.barriers[13] = picBlock4Part2;
            this.barriers[14] = picBlock4Part3;
            this.barriers[15] = picBlock4Part4;
            this.barriers[16] = picBlock5Part1;
            this.barriers[17] = picBlock5Part2;
            this.barriers[18] = picBlock5Part3;
            this.barriers[19] = picBlock5Part4;

            this.Aliens = new PictureBox[8];
            this.Aliens[0] = picBigAlien1;
            this.Aliens[1] = picBigAlien2;
            this.Aliens[2] = picBigAlien3;
            this.Aliens[3] = picBigAlien4;
            this.Aliens[4] = picBigAlien5;
            this.Aliens[5] = picBigAlien6;
            this.Aliens[6] = picBigAlien7;
            this.Aliens[7] = picBigAlien8;

            this.Aliens2 = new PictureBox[8];
            this.Aliens2[0] = picBigAlien9;
            this.Aliens2[1] = picBigAlien10;
            this.Aliens2[2] = picBigAlien11;
            this.Aliens2[3] = picBigAlien12;
            this.Aliens2[4] = picBigAlien13;
            this.Aliens2[5] = picBigAlien14;
            this.Aliens2[6] = picBigAlien15;
            this.Aliens2[7] = picBigAlien16;

            if(picBigAlien1.Visible == false)
            {
                ScoreNum = ScoreNum + 10;
            }
            else
            {
                ScoreNum = ScoreNum + 0;
            }

            String ScoreNumD = ScoreNum.ToString();
            ScoreBox1.Text = ScoreNumD;
        }

        private bool CheckBulletCollision()
        {
            //Check if the players bullet collides with the barriers
            foreach (PictureBox barrier in this.barriers)
            {
                if ((barrier != null) && (barrier.Visible))
                {
                    if (picLaser.Bounds.IntersectsWith(barrier.Bounds))
                    {
                        barrier.Visible = false;
                        picLaser.Visible = false;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (PictureBox Alien in this.Aliens)
            {
                if ((Alien != null) && (Alien.Visible))
                {
                    this.picLaser.Top -= 1;
                    Rectangle picLaserBounds = picLaser.Bounds;

                    picLaserBounds = new Rectangle(picLaserBounds.Left - panAliens.Left,
                        picLaserBounds.Top - panAliens.Top, picLaserBounds.Width, picLaserBounds.Height);
                    if (picLaserBounds.IntersectsWith(Alien.Bounds))
                    {
                        Alien.Visible = false;
                        picLaser.Visible = false;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (PictureBox Alien in this.Aliens2)
            {
                if ((Alien != null) && (Alien.Visible))
                {
                    this.picLaser.Top -= 1;
                    Rectangle picLaserBounds = picLaser.Bounds;

                    picLaserBounds = new Rectangle(picLaserBounds.Left - panAlien2.Left,
                        picLaserBounds.Top - panAlien2.Top, picLaserBounds.Width, picLaserBounds.Height);
                    if (picLaserBounds.IntersectsWith(Alien.Bounds))
                    {
                        Alien.Visible = false;
                        picLaser.Visible = false;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void timUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Moves the aliens
            if (this.direction)
            {
                panAliens.Left -= 1;
                if (panAliens.Left < 10)
                {
                    panAliens.Left = 10;
                    this.direction = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                panAliens.Left += 1;
                if (panAliens.Right > this.Width - 10)
                {
                    panAliens.Left = this.Width - 10 - panAliens.Width;
                    this.direction = true;
                }
            }
            if (this.direction)
            {
                panAlien2.Left -= 1;
                if (panAlien2.Left < 10)
                {
                    panAlien2.Left = 10;
                    this.direction = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                panAlien2.Left += 1;
                if (panAlien2.Right > this.Width - 10)
                {
                    panAlien2.Left = this.Width - 10 - panAlien2.Width;
                    this.direction = true;
                }
            }
            //Moves the users bullet
            if (this.picLaser.Visible)
            {

                this.picLaser.Top -= 3;
                if (this.picLaser.Bottom < 0)
                    this.picLaser.Visible = false;
                else
                    this.CheckBulletCollision();
            }
        }

        private void timUpdateRow_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Moves the aliens towards the player
            panAliens.Top++;
            //Moves the aliens towards the player
            panAlien2.Top++;
        }

        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            //Process the key presses off the user
            switch (keyData)
            {
                //User moves left
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.A:
                    this.picPlayer.Left -= 5;
                    if (this.picPlayer.Left < 10)
                        this.picPlayer.Left = 10;
                    return true;
                //User moves right
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.D:
                    this.picPlayer.Left += 5;
                    if (this.picPlayer.Right > this.Width - 10)
                        this.picPlayer.Left = this.Width - this.picPlayer.Width - 10;
                    return true;
                //Allows the player to shoot
                case Keys.Space:
                    if (!this.picLaser.Visible)
                    {
                        this.picLaser.Top = this.picPlayer.Top;
                        this.picLaser.Left = this.picPlayer.Left + (this.picPlayer.Width / 2);
                        this.picLaser.Visible = true;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }

        private void frmSpace_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

    }
}
```

(C)

Comment: I think you're on to something with the code being in the wrong place (hint). Where are you setting it false (where are you setting the aliens false)? Check it where you are setting the Alien.Visible false, if it's _that_ Alien that is now false add your 10 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class constructor `frmSpace()` is only called once, when the form is instantiated. You need to move the visible check to one of the tick event handlers. This alone will cause the score to increase rapidly as long as the alien is not visible, so if you want to prevent that you'll need to filter out subsequent hits on the alien visibility. You also don't need the else branch, since it does absolutely nothing.

I'm not sure which tick you want to associate the visibility check with, so I'll leave that to you.

At the top of the class add something like:

```
Boolean bigAlienWasVisible = true;
```

Then move this into your timer and structure it like so:

```
if(bigAlienWasVisible && picBigAlien1.Visible == false)
{
    ScoreNum = ScoreNum + 10;
    bigAlienWasVisible = false;
    ScoreBox1.Text = ScoreNum.ToString();
}
```

At this point, you'll get an exception when this attempts to update the score because you cannot directly update the UI from a background thread, which is what the timer creates. This line will not work in a background thread:

```
ScoreBox1.Text = ScoreNum.ToString();
```

instead it will need to be invoked by the UI Invoker like this:

```
Invoke((Action)(() => ScoreBox1.Text = ScoreNum.ToString()));
```

The above is shorthand to simplify what is handled with delegates. Read up on C# delegates, because when you start involving timer-driven actions with forms you *must* also understand the use of delegates to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only place where you set the points is in the constructor of your frmSpace.  The constructor will be called only once, when your frmSpace will get initialized.

You'll have decide which event will update the points (you didn't mention anything about it) and then write your point logic inside this event.  Since you have trouble finding the right place where your code should be written, I'll assume you're not familiar with events concept.  I won't explain everything here but basically, you'll have to decide when your code score should be updated: is it when a button will be clicked? Every X seconds? When you press a keyboard key?  After answering that question you'll have to find out which object on your form will raise this event and write your code in that event's callback method.

Note: In your else statement, you add 0 to your `scoreNum` variable... this is useless and you could simple remove the else from your point logic.